# Does IE9 support the new CSS3 four-value background-position syntax?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, css-sprites

The current CSS3 recommendation (the be exact [this candidate version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/)) gives new possibilities for positioning background-images, that may prove very useful when working with CSS sprites.

I am particularly interested in the possibility to bottom position the background while also adding an offset (from the bottom of the image), so this:

```
#container {
  background-image:url(sprite.png);
  background-position:bottom -100px left 0;
}
```

would take my `sprite.png` image, stick it to the bottom of my `#container` element and then *drag it down* by 100 px so that the bottom 100 px of that image will not show. the image would then fill up from the bottom as high as the `#container` is.

This works fine in Chrome (Version 29.0.1547.76 m), Firefox (24.0) and IE10. But I cannot test on IE9. Does IE9 support this new syntax?

I have an old Windows XP machine on which I can test in IE8 and it definitely does not work.

**Edit**

I have had the opportunity to do some tests and I can confirm that it works in IE9 (tested in Win7 Pro 32bit)

Comment: I think this is the "official" URL for the recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

Comment: @PaulD.Waite you are pointing to the "current" version. Just in case it changes dramatically (which it most likely won't) I wanted to reference the exact version that described the behaviour I'm taking about (because this needs to be archived for eternity ;) ).

Comment: Ah yes I see. Yes, as it’s a Recommendation, I don’t think it will change —if I understand correctly, that’s pretty much the final state of W3C standards. Always good to future-proof though, well done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four-value syntax is supported as of IE9.0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-position

Comment: Good news everyone! Thanks for digging that up.